# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request - uploading less 2MB file size?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, httpwebresponse

The file succeed to upload when it is 2KB or lower in size. The main reason why I use streaming is to be able to upload file up to at least 1 GB. But when I try to upload file with less 1MB size, I get bad request. It is my first time to deal with downloading and uploading process, so I can't easily find the cause of error.

Testing part:

```
private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openfile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string port = "3445";
            byte[] fileStream;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(openfile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                fileStream = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(fileStream, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
            }

            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:" + port + "/File/AddStream?fileID=9";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(baseAddress);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/plain";
            //request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Stream serverStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            serverStream.Write(fileStream, 0, fileStream.Length);
            serverStream.Close();
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddStream?fileID={fileID}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public bool AddStream(long fileID, System.IO.Stream fileStream)
{
    ClasslLogic.FileComponent svc = new ClasslLogic.FileComponent();
    return svc.AddStream(fileID, fileStream);
}
```

Server code for streaming:

```
namespace ClasslLogic
{
    public class StreamObject : IStreamObject
    {
        public bool UploadFile(string filename, Stream fileStream)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
                byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
                int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                } while (bytesRead > 0);

                fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                fileToupload.Close();
                fileToupload.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Web config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2097152" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="ClassLogicBasicTransfer" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="67108864" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BaseLogicWSHTTP">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BaseLogicWSHTTPSec" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm not sure if this affects the streaming function, because I'm using WCF4.0 rest template 
which config is dependent in Global.asax.

One more thing is this, whether I run the service and passing a stream or not, the created file always contain this thing.

[image]

How could I remove the "NUL" data?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

```
public bool UploadFile(string filename, Stream fileStream)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
                byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
                int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, totalBytesRead, bytearray.Length - totalBytesRead);
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                } while (bytesRead > 0);

                fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, totalBytesRead);
                fileToupload.Close();
                fileToupload.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason you're seeing nulls is because of the following line.  You're initializing a buffer, but you're probably not filling that entire buffer:

```
fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
fileToupload.Close();
fileToupload.Dispose();
```

It should instead be:

```
fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, totalBytesRead);
fileToupload.Close();
fileToupload.Dispose();
```

You're also always overwriting your buffer within each loop iteration:

```
fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length)`.
```

When you probably want this, as it continues to fill the rest of your buffer:

```
fileStream.Read(bytearray, totalBytesRead, byteArray.Length - totalBytesRead);
```

However, if you move the code that writes to the file inside your loop, then you will only have to make minimal changes to your existing code:

```
int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
do
{
    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} while (bytesRead > 0);
```

You will receive 400 if you try to send more data than the MaxReceivedMessageSize.  Adjust it accordingly:

```
<binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
```

Comment: +1 nulls has been remove. But still having bad request when file size is up to 1MB or more. Do you have any idea for this? thanks

Comment: @ryan, add `maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760"` to the Binding that you are using in your endpoint. This will allow you to upload files of up to 10MB

Comment: Just to be clear, you can upload files larger than 10MB, but the value I pasted above would limit it to 10MB

Comment: I'm sorry for this last question. The file I'm uploading is 800KB, but it only creates the file for 10KB, maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760". What's wrong with this? thanks

Comment: Hey @ryan, did you use the server code that I pasted.  The one that you originally posted can never grow beyond 10KB

Comment: Please see the edited question. I've used your second suggestion. The code under "However, if you move..." doesn't eliminate [NUL] data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8905/discussion-between-tung-and-ryan)